# Weird behaviour regarding FQDN/IE/Security zones

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer, fqdn, security-zones

We've deployed our Java web app on a customers site that we've deployed hundreds of times without any problems, but this one customer is experiencing weird issues regarding security zones in IE.

Basically they're using a FQDN instead of just the server name, in conjunction with SSL (which I think is irrelevant). They access our web app from a bunch of static HTML pages within the same domain (using the same FQDN) but when our web app first loads up in IE it's being shown as a Internet site, not Intranet. Clicking refresh in IE seems to refresh the zone and it switches to the Intranet zone (or Trusted, I can't remember which).

What could be causing this issue? It doesn't behave like this on all machines, or for all users, but it does appear to be a little random.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. They're running Server 2008, XP and IE 8.

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

A little more information regarding the environment would help, I push most IE settings via Group Policy.

See the steps in this article http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/325-deploy-ie-trusted-sites-through-group-policy-2008 on how to deploy Trusted sites via Windows Server 2008 Group Policy

Comment: Unfortunately, this is about as much as I know. I think it's their GPOs that's the issue, but they're thinking it's our web app. If you log in directly from our home page to the web app it seems to be more successful (as opposed to through the static pages). I have a colleague/engineer going on site tomorrow to have another look. What other information about the environment would be useful? I've asked the engineer to go back to basics and use the server name (not the FQDN), and remove the SSL. Then apply each until it seems problematic. I'm hoping this sheds some light.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the SSL is configured for the server name AND the FQDN?  Is the web app programmed to leverage the server name only?